# How to make a new command that uses a string with percentage?

Tags: macros

I'm working in a group that have made a website for the group members to submit a short presentation about their weekly work, and this is done using a TeX-like setup.

Unfortunately, the admin have changed some of the commands into commands that can't be run directly from my computer in normal TeX-setup, and I would like to write my presentation on my own machine before submitting.

One of these commands are `\includegraphics`. 
Such that if I want to include an image, perhaps using `\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{stuff.png}`, this is now equivalent to `\image{stuff.png}{width="30%"}`.

If I don't want to include the width, I just set

```
\newcommand{\image}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]}
```

however, this means the width is always set to 100% the line width.

So the question becomes: how do I include a changeable width - one that is directly set using a percentage-character?

Comment: sorry your question is quite unclear. How is `\image{stuff.png}{width="30%"}` processed on the website? With tex? Then why don't you ask the admin about the definition and copy it to your local setup?

Comment: Well, it is processed using TeX, but I wanted to avoid going to the admin since it seems like a possibly easy fix?

Comment: Well I think the admin made this custom command and should now handle the problems involved with it.

Comment: sorry your question is quite hard to understand.  what do you mean by "admin changed commands"? They can not change the latex system, why do you need width =30% rather than `width=.3\textwidth` which will work?

Comment: Well, I did have a hard time explaining the problem..
When I try to use normal latex-commands such as `\includegraphics`, I get an error, since this have not been included as a command on the website. I guess they have some program that takes a text-block, looks through familiar commands they have defined (such as `\image`), and runs it through a latex compiler` with \newcommand{\image}{\includegraphics}. They haven't defined `\includegraphics`, and is thus not recognised..

Comment: Your question specifically mentioned the percentage character.  This is an easy problem without that one detail, as you can just move the decimal point back two places and enter it as `0.45\linewidth` for `45%`, for example.  But if you specifically need the percentage character, you're going to need a needlessly complex macro, I think.

Comment: Wouldn't a syntax such as `pwidth=30` be better? You know, `%` is a very special character for TeX and while it's possible to cope with it at the “outer level”, an `\image` command depending on `%` cannot go in the argument to any other command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp,graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\isnum#1{\pst@isnum@i\zap@space#1 \@empty\@nil}%
\def\pst@isnum@i#1\@nil{%
  \if!\ifnum9<1#1!\else_\fi%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi}
\NewDocumentCommand\image{ m v }{%
  \if$#2$\edef\IScale{100}\else\checkScale#2\@nil\fi
  \includegraphics[scale=\fpeval{\IScale/100}]{#1}%
}
\def\checkScale#1="#2#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \isnum{#2#3#4}{\edef\IScale{#2#3#4}}{%
    \isnum{#2#3}{\edef\IScale{#2#3}}{\edef\IScale{#2}}}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\image{tiger}{width="30%"}

\image{tiger}{width="3%"}

\image{tiger}{width="100%"}

\image{tiger}{}% same as 100%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the image-command looks like
`\image{image.png}{width="30%"}`

Comment: ups. See edited answer ...

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! 
Is it possible to set a default value of 100%? Right now I have to set {width="100%"} each call :)

Comment: something like `\image{tiger}{}`??

Comment: I would prefer if you could just write `\image{tiger}`, but if `\image{tiger}{}` is the only possible, I can live with that ;)

Comment: `\tiger{}` is a lot more work ... maybe later ...

Answer (score 2):

Your admin has bad ideas about TeX: `%` is a very special character.

I'm not sure what's the advantage of `\image{name}{width="30%"}` over `\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{name}`.

The following works and also allows explicit widths to be set. However, don't try using `\image` in the argument to another command.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\image}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_other:n { `\% }
  \peek_catcode:NTF \c_group_begin_token
   {
    \anders_image:nn { #1 }
   }
   {
    \anders_image:nn { #1 } { }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__anders_image_include:nn
 {
  \includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__anders_image_include:nn { x }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__anders_image_include:nn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \anders_image:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \keys_set:nn { anders/image } { width=\linewidth }
   }
   {
    \keys_set:nn { anders/image } { #2 }
   }
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { " } { \tl_head:N \l__anders_image_width_tl }
   {
    \__anders_image_include:xn
     {
      \fp_eval:n
       {
        (\tl_range:Nnn \l__anders_image_width_tl { 2 } { -3 })/100
       }
      \linewidth
     }
     { #1 }
   }
   {
    \__anders_image_include:Vn \l__anders_image_width_tl { #1 }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { anders/image }
 {
  width .tl_set:N = \l__anders_image_width_tl,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\centering

\image{example-image}

\image{example-image}{width="30%"}

\image{example-image}{width=0.3\textwidth}

\image{example-image}{width=2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]